# ActiveReports Conditional Formatting - Picture Visibility

Tags: c#, formatting, conditional-statements, activereports

In ActiveReports, how can I change formatting based on values in the report data?

Specifically, I want to show or hide pictures based on a value in the data. The report gets bound to a list of objects via a set to its DataSource property. These objects have a `Condition` property with values "Poor", "Normal", etc. I have some pictures in the report that correspond to the different conditions, and I want to hide all the pictures except for the one corresponding to the value.

Should I subscribe to the `Format` event for the detail section? If so, how do I get to the "current record" data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Ok, I still don't know how to get the current data object, but I discovered that you can use the report's `Fields` property to retrieve values off the current data object.</s>

<s>The code below subscribes to the detail section's `Format` event. `Fields["Condition"].Value` gets the value of the current data object's `Condition` property (which happens to be an enum value).</s>

```
    private void detail_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Condition? condition = Fields["Condition"].Value as Condition?;

        conditionUnknownPicture.Visible = (condition == Condition.Unknown);
        conditionPoorPicture.Visible = (condition == Condition.Poor);
        conditionNormalPicture.Visible = (condition == Condition.Normal);
        conditionNewPicture.Visible = (condition == Condition.New);
    }
```

**Edit:**

I've since learned that accessing the Fields collection from a Format event is against the ActiveReports design rules, because it doesn't work in certain weird corner cases. I now use this method instead: http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=133642#133642

DataDynamics has a feature request 22786 to provide access to the data objects from Format events.